# Best practice to pass data to CustomClassB that's an attribute of CustomClassA from main class

Tags: java

I want to get data to my CustomClassB which is an attribute in my CustomClassA, I've managed to get around it, but I'm not sure it's the best practice.

CustomClassA:

```
public class CustomClassA() {
   private CustomClassB customClassB;

   //constructor CustomClassA...

   public void passInfo(Foo foo) {
      this.customClassB.receiveFoo(foo);
   }
}
```

As for CustomClassB:

```
public class CustomClassB () {
   private Foo foo;

   //constructor CustomClassB...

   public void receiveFoo(Foo foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
   }
}
```

What I have to do from my main class is something like:

```
customClassA.passInfo(foo);
```

I searched but only got linked to "nested classes", and that's not what I'm looking for, maybe my searching skills are not that good. Hope someone can help!
Thank you!

Comment: Method delegate - looks fine to me ;)

Comment: Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: @shmosel It works, I'm just not sure if it's the best way to do it. I'm imagining having CustomClassXYZ attributes inside other classes and creating mutiple methods that have noting to do with the class they're being created in, just to pass on some data.

Comment: It's hard to help with so little information. Anyway, this is probably a better fit for [codereview.se], but be warned, they expect to see your real code, not abstract snippets.

Comment: @shmosel thanks for the suggestion. I used abstract snippets to simplify, this is for a school project, I have to problem sharing more information.
Edit: Class Station receives Class Bike from Main class, to store in a Dock, which is an attribute of the class Terminal wich is an attribute of the class Station.
When and user leaves the bike, the system has to store it in the dock, with the implementation I have I have to create a method in the class Station just to pass the Bike into the Terminal

Answer (score 0):

Second option for you is call this method in this way:

```
customClassA.getCustomClassB().setFoo(foo);
```

You have to make:

```
public class CustomClassA {
    private CustomClassB customClassB;

   //constructor CustomClassA...

   public CustomClassB getCustomClassB(){
      return customClassB;
   }
}


public class CustomClassB  {
    private Foo foo;
    //constructor CustomClassB...
    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

You can read about getters and setters and Java Beans API.

Comment: returning the original CustomClassB is a security problem, right?
and if I return a copy it wont affect the instance I want

Comment: I return object customClassB from instance customClassA. You do this in the same way. You operate on object customClassB created in customClassA object.

Comment: @BrunoTeixeira what kind of security issue ?